# Book about a girl raised by a computer

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I have been looking for years, on and off, for a book that I can only assume is Fantasy/SciFi.

The story starts out with a young girl in an empty facility with no other beings to interact with other then a computer system. You begin with her growing up and asking the computer questions and exploring the facility. Even in the book, the description is a bit vague about when and where this is, which is what drove me the most about what was going on.

Anyways, the girl goes through puberty and such, oh also, she is described as naked throughout the series, I don't recall why I remember that point, but I remember it was something to do with noticing her changes. Anyways, she starts to explore the empty facility and finds a door that the main systems tells her not to go through, something or the other. Well she finds a way and discovers a male about her age in that side of the facility.

I don't recall much of what happens next but I know that they spend time trying to understand what is going on in the facility and why they are similar but different. Well, thinking on it it sounds like a book about puberty in sexual urges in a sterile and innocent futuristic environment. I do remember the ending is them leaving the facility that they thought was maybe in space, but turns out they are on a planet.

I know I read this between 2003-2008, but is seemed a bit old when I grabbed it from my local library. It had a hard cover, was definitely over 200 pgs about an inch thick. I feel strongly about it being in the fantasy section of the library, was not in the young readers or teen reads. This was adult themed with some mild sexual interaction. (Them discovering what sex is and learning about who and what they are). I think the computer program was a colonization program that restarted and produced a male and female in hopes to restart the human race again. It purposely kept to two unaware of each other and of the outside would I think.

Well it's late at night here and I just wish I knew the name of that book. I still remember what it was like visualizing the world it was in. It was a good book. In effort to try and find it I always end up at dead ends or revisiting some books I have already read. This one means a lot to me though. If you know anything about this book or something similar please contact me. Anything would help and if you want me to clarify on something then let me know, I will do my best to remember.

Comment: I have either read that or something similar. The one I read had something about the computers becoming self-aware and becoming curious about a code that is always replicated in their programming. They had to figure out what it was (DNA coding for humans) and then figure out how to grow whatever they were. Is this the one you read or am I thinking of a different story?

Comment: No chance it could be this, right? Boy, girl, raised by computers (and aliens, though): http://www.amazon.com/Alien-Child-Pamela-Sargent/product-reviews/0064470024/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_btm?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=recent

Comment: @Jonah: I'd say that's a good enough match for an answer. It might be a bit late for Guzman, but I was the one who put up the bounty.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I don't think it really matches, unless the OP mis-remembered a few things.

Comment: @Jonah: Eh. I dunno. You have the starting protagonist a girl, later finding there is a guy, sexual discovery (at least according to the reviews I've seen), revelation that they are on a post-apocalyptic Earth. They didn't mention the alien, but that might have slipped their mind.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - If you read one of the reviews, it says that the protagonist saw the other human on an intercom, not by wandering into a forbidden part of the facility.

Comment: Well, up to you. I would personally argue for posting it if for no other reason than that, some day, someone looking for Alien Planet may plug in similar keywords and will find an answer here.

Comment: OK...but I might try to find the actual story first.

Comment: @Kaine: I know this reply is coming many years late, but for viewers of this question, I think *your* book is probably "Star Child" by James P. Hogan:  AI's on a deep-space exploratory vessel have forgotten where they originally came from, but experimenting with DNA data they have on file, eventually manage to clone a human girl (and later some other kids).  Returning to Earth, they find some catastrophe has wiped out scientific knowledge, and they reintroduce it.  Definitely similar to the OP's description, but not exactly.  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/849495.Star_Child

Comment: Not the answer but it's sounds a very similar plot to I Am Mother. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Mother

Answer (score 9):

### This is similar to *Alien Child*

**Note: This is not the answer, but it is sufficiently similar that someone using the same keywords might find it. I was therefore encouraged to post it.**

[image: Book cover]

As indicated in the reviews, this features a

- girl
- raised partly by computers
- who encounters another human, a boy
- and has some sexual interaction with him.

Unfortunately, it may diverge in other respects, such as the manner in which the girl finds the other human; the protagonist saw the other human on an intercom, not by wandering into a forbidden part of the facility.

Although, from comments:

> [Goodreads review](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/869290.Alien_Child) says something about a forbidden part of the facility: "And what is Llipel's companion, Llare, occupied by, in the parts of the complex that have been forbidden to Nita?" –
> Malady - Feb 9, 2017 at 2:40
>
> It *is* the book. As she grows older, she begins to wonder if there are any people who look like her. Then she discovers that a boy her age, Sven, lives in another wing of the building with a creature called Llare. –
> Kinzle B - Feb 9, 2017 at 6:02

And the OP believes it may be the right book:

> I went searching for the book again and was actually pleasantly surprise to find that my post was the first link on Google search. I believe you two may have found the book I have been looking for for years!!! The cover triggered me and I currently purchased the book to read it as soon as possible. I can't wait to read it. I want to thank you guys so much!!! I truly hope it is. –
> Guzman - Jun 14, 2017 at 8:08

Comment: Bounty is into the grace period. I'm awarding it to you for being the closest so far.

Comment: This [Goodreads review](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/869290.Alien_Child) says something about a forbidden part of the facility:  "And what is Llipel's companion, Llare, occupied by, in the parts of the complex that have been forbidden to Nita?"

Comment: @Malandy - I don’t know. Maybe it is the right one, then. I usually only post an answer when I’m certain, but this was an exception.

Comment: It *is* the book. As she grows older, she begins to wonder if there are any people who look like her. Then she discovers that a boy her age, Sven, lives in another wing of the building with a creature called Llare.

Comment: I went searching for the book again and was actually pleasantly surprise to find that my post was the first link on Google search. I believe you two may have found the book I have been looking for for years!!! The cover triggered me and I currently purchased the book to read it as soon as possible. I can't wait to read it. I want to thank you guys so much!!! I truly hope it is.

Comment: @Guzman - If you read it and it turns out to be the one, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark.